# JS Fetch API - When should I use credentials option with "omit" value if by default fetch won't send or receive any cookies from the server?

Tags: javascript, credentials, fetch-api

On the MDN Fetch API page ([Sending a request with credentials included](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Sending_a_request_with_credentials_included) section) it is written that:

> To instead ensure browsers don’t include credentials in the request, use credentials: 'omit'.

```
fetch('https://example.com', {
  credentials: 'omit'  
})
```

However, initially, it is also written that:

> By default, fetch **won't send or receive** any cookies from the server, resulting in unauthenticated requests if the site relies on maintaining a user session (to send cookies, the credentials init option must be set).

My question is, if I want to omit cookies and auth headers, why should I ever bother to use `credentials: 'omit'` in the first place if it is written that by default (without `credentials`), `fetch` won't send cookies?

Comment: I feel this is more related to dealing with the header [Access-Control-Allow-Credentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials).

Comment: I think MDN has some confusing documentation. In firefox, If you create a [Request object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request), the default for credentials is "same-origin" - even though the documentation states that the default is "omit"

Comment: Further reading suggests different browsers have different default values (at least creating a Request Object, firefox apparently defaults to omit, and chrome defaults to either same-origin or include, depending on the version - therefore it makes sense for the documentation to document all valid options

Answer (score 8):

Because of this discussion on [whatwg/fetch](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/pull/585), the default value was changed from `omit` to `same-origin` in late 2017.

Browsers were catching up in 2018 so you can see some older browsers still use `omit`. For example, Firefox changed from `omit` to `same-origin` starting from 61. Chrome changed from version 72. You may check the full list [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/credentials#Browser_compatibility).

And more interestingly, the standard on [whatwg page](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-credentials-mode) (Last updated 23 Mar 2019) is still `omit`.

Comment: So this means that the MDN documentation page is not up to date?

Comment: Now the MDN has a little footnote in the page: "Since Aug 25, 2017. The spec changed the default credentials policy to same-origin. Firefox changed since 61.0b13."